# notification is not working in android

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

I am trying to push notification at the certain time. To perform this I am triggering the alarm which eventually call the broadcast receiver that show the notifications.

```
private void setAlarmToCallNotificationService(Context context, int request_code, String notificationText, String notificationTitle) {

        Log.i("Inside notification,","Yes");

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, notificationService.class);
        intent.putExtra("Notification_title",notificationTitle);
        intent.putExtra("Notification_text",notificationText);


        //hit the notification At the 8.00 in the morning
        Calendar notificationCalendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        notificationCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,16);
        notificationCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,29);
        notificationCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

        Long time=notificationCalendar.getTimeInMillis();

        System.out.println("NOTIFICATION Time is "+notificationCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+" "+notificationCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        Log.i("Target",time.toString());

        //final int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, request_code, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);

    }
```

I checked that the alarm is firing up.

```
public class notificationService extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String TAG="notificationService";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String notificatioTitle=intent.getExtras().getString("Notification_title");
        String notificationMsg=intent.getExtras().getString("Notification_text");

        Log.i(TAG,"Notification title "+notificatioTitle);
        Log.i(TAG,"Notification msg "+notificationMsg);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notification=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(notificatioTitle)
                .setContentText(notificationMsg);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(0,notification.build());
    }


}
```

Manifest file:

```
 <receiver android:name=".notificationService" />
```

Comment: why so many downvotes? can anyone explain.

Answer (score 0):

Did your receiver receive intent at expected time?

I mean... did the code below print anything at all?

```
Log.i(TAG,"Notification title "+notificatioTitle);
Log.i(TAG,"Notification msg "+notificationMsg);
```

If no, check if you use `Settings.System.AUTO_TIME` in you device `DateTimeSettings`,
You may need to use NTP time to set alarm.

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - ntpTimeOffset;
long timeToWaitForTrigger = calendar.getTimeInMillis() - currentTime;
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + timeToWaitForTrigger, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: I am using almost same function for launching the dialog then but that is working but why not this is working.@Skeeter

Comment: yup my notification receiver is not receiving the intent at the expected time. But I am firing the alarm with the same code but with different time  which call another broadcast receiver(this broadcast receiver is working ) to do some calculation which then call this this notification service(this broadcast receiver is not receiving the intent) receiver to fire up the notification.